# ListField without duplicates in Python mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, unique, mongoengine

I must be missing something really obvious. But I can't seem to find a way to represent a set using mongoengine.

```
class Item(Document):
    name = StringField(required=True)
    description = StringField(max_length=50)
    parents = ListField(ReferenceField('self'))

i = Item.objects.get_or_create(name='test item')[0]

i2 = Item(name='parents1')
i2.save()
i3 = Item(name='parents3')
i3.save()
i.parents.append(i2)
i.parents.append(i2)
i.parents.append(i3)
i.save()
```

The above code will create a duplicate entry for i2 in the parents field of i1. How do you express a foreign key like relationship in mongoengine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using `append` then using `save` and letting MongoEngine convert that to updates, you could use atomic updates and the $addToSet method - see [the updating mongoDB docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating)

So in your case you could do:

```
i.update(add_to_set__parents=i2)
i.update(add_to_set__parents=i3)
i.update(add_to_set__parents=i2)
```

Support for `addToSet` and `each` doesn't currently exist - see: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/33

**Update:**

[add_to_set](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#atomic-updates) is supported.